# Cloud Data Fusion - How to read field value in a Conditional plugin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to create a Cloud Data Fusion pipeline that makes an HTTP call to a WS, and then has a "conditional" plugin that evaluates the content of the response, so that one node or another is executed depending on the result, but I can't seem to get the conditional plugin to correctly evaluate the response of the prior HTTP plugin, I don't know if it's due to a mistake in the syntax that I use or a plugin limitation.

The service can return 2 different messages:

```
{"example":null}
```

or:

```
{
     {"example":
     {"subfieldA": value1},
     {subfieldB": value2}
}
```

So I have tried the following options:
1.- Evaluate if the incoming message contains a given string:

```
token['HTTP']['output'] =~ ".*subfieldA.*"
```

Unsuccessful, always returns false

2.- Evaluate if the size of the message is greater than 20 characters (the first example message is 16 characters long):

```
size(token['HTTP']['output']) >20.
```

Unsuccessful, always returns false

3.- Evaluate if the incoming message is different from the first example message:

```
token['HTTP']]['output'] != "{'example':null}"
```

I get a data type error, and I can't get it to work escaping the special characters with "".

> Type mismatch. Change type of constant or convert to right data type
> using conversion functions available. Reason : For input string:
> "{'example':null}"

What would be the correct way to access the plugin output message before the conditional (or any of its fields)?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in condition plugin has access to the token, which includes metrics from previous stages, but not access to the actual data that was processed. The plugin also has access to the runtime arguments that are submitted along with the request to start the run.

One way to accomplish your use case would be to have the condition on a runtime argument, and move the logic of calling the WS to whatever is launching the pipeline. Call the WS and depending on the result, start the pipeline with the corresponding value for that argument.

Alternatively, if you want all the logic to be maintained within the pipeline itself, you would have to write a custom condition plugin (see https://github.com/data-integrations/condition-plugins as an example) that makes the WS call and branches accordingly.